# Ridge Estimator in Summation Form

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, estimation, matrix, ridge-regression

I am trying to derive $\widehat{\beta}$ in summation form from the following:

$$\text{argmin } \sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i - X_i^{T}\beta)^2 + \lambda \sum_{k=1}^{K}{\beta}_k^2$$

I do not want to resort to matrix calculus, I want to use the fact that the sum of the derivative is the derivative of the sum in the finite case.

So I converted the top to:

$$\text{argmin } \sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^{K} X_{ij}\beta_j)^2 + \lambda \sum_{k=1}^{K}\beta_k^2$$

And differentiating term by term and setting the results to $0$ I get the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}X_{ik}y_i = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}X_{ik}^{2}{\beta}_{k} + \lambda \sum_{k=1}^{K}{\beta}_k$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}X_{ik}y_i = \sum_{k=1}^{K}{\beta}_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}^{2} + \lambda \sum_{k=1}^{K}{\beta}_k$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}X_{ik}y_i = \sum_{k=1}^{K}{\beta}_{k}(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}^{2} + \lambda)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{K}{\beta}_{k} = (\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}^{2} + \lambda)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}X_{ik}y_i $$

In matrix form this gives:

$$ \widehat{\beta}^{\text{RIDGE}} = (X^TX + \lambda)^{-1}(X^TY)$$

Is this correct? ANY help would be greatly appreaciated, I already posted this on MSE, but I figured I would get a better answer on cross validated, I will delete one or the other if I'm not allowed to this

Thanks!

Comment: solution looks right except you are missing the Identity matrix multiplying the lambda in matrix form

Comment: @seanv507 thank you!